# Where clause returns different result with same logic

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm new in sql and I have where clause like this:

**First Query (production)**

```
WHERE [D].[IsLocked] = 0
                        AND ((@FilterEmpKey IS NULL
                        AND [TA].[EmpKey] = @CurrentEmpKey)
                         OR (ISNULL([TA].[ModifiedAssignedBy] , [TA].[AssignatedBy]) = @FilterEmpKey
                        AND [TA].[EmpKey] = @CurrentEmpKey))
```

**Second Query(test)**

```
WHERE [D].[IsLocked] = 0 
              AND  [TA].EmpKey = @CurrentEmpKey  
              OR (ISNULL([TA].[ModifiedAssignedBy] , [TA].[AssignatedBy]) = @FilterEmpKey
              AND [TA].[EmpKey] = @CurrentEmpKey)
```

I want to know what is the difference between first and second query, because result is not the same and I don't know why?.  Regards

> Note: my desire result is get value of test query

Comment: And why don't you use the same query on both systems?

Comment: I need to evaluate  `@FilterEmpKey` don't come null somethimes, so first one evaluate that, second one no but in testing both have `@FilterEmpKey` but I don't know why I have different results, I guess something is wrong with parentesis on first query @sticky bit

Comment: Aside: `AssignatedBy`, see [assignation](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/assignation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example. The queries return different result sets when @FilterEmpKey IS NOT NULL and @CurrentEmpKey matches TA.EmpKey.

```
CREATE TABLE TA (EmpKey VARCHAR(25), ModifiedAssignedBy VARCHAR(25), AssignatedBy VARCHAR(25))
INSERT INTO TA VALUES ('test', 'test_mod', 'test_assign')

DECLARE @FilterEmpKey VARCHAR(25) = 'banana'
DECLARE @CurrentEmpKey VARCHAR(25) = 'test'

-- Returns nothing; both conditions are false.
SELECT * FROM TA
WHERE  ((@FilterEmpKey IS NULL
                        AND [TA].[EmpKey] = @CurrentEmpKey)
                         OR (ISNULL([TA].[ModifiedAssignedBy] , [TA].[AssignatedBy]) = @FilterEmpKey
                        AND [TA].[EmpKey] = @CurrentEmpKey))

-- Returns a row; first condition is true.
SELECT * FROM TA
WHERE [TA].EmpKey = @CurrentEmpKey  
              OR (ISNULL([TA].[ModifiedAssignedBy] , [TA].[AssignatedBy]) = @FilterEmpKey
              AND [TA].[EmpKey] = @CurrentEmpKey)
```